# Using stemming in a SOLR query

Tags: solr, stemming

I've set up SOLR, and added a document to the example 'collection1'.

```
<doc>
    <str name="id">3007WFP</str>
    <str name="name">Fishing</str>
    <str name="type">Ladies</str>
</doc>
```

I can query it ok in the interface using

```
name:*fishing*
```

but I would like to get stemming to work, so that I can e.g. type `fish` and get this document due to the word `fishing` being stemmed. I'd also like to be able to find `Ladies` when `Lady` is searched for.

However I have tried the query

```
name:fish
```

and I get no results. I didn't add the wildcard as I know that will match, and only want to test the stemming function.

I've changed the schema type of both the name and type fields to `text_en` which I believe includes stemming - restarted SOLR, and reindexed (clicked optimise).

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong, is the query syntax different when you want to use stemming?

Another strange issue is after the change from `text_general` to `text_en` a search for

`name:Fishing`

produces no results, even though it should be an exact match..

Comment: Could you help me with the text_general and text_en description?

Answer (score 2):

Clicking optimize won't re-index the documents. It will simply merge the various segments in your existing index, which means your index is still old. So once you re-post i.e. re-index your documents, `name:fish` should match.

BTW, you can look into what the analyzer is doing at `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/analysis`. You can choose the fieldType and see what happens at index time. For example, using this tool you can see that for `text_en` type,

```
fishing -> fish
ladies -> ladi
```

so a search for `type:lady` won't match this document. If you also specify your query at 'Field Value (Query)' it will highlight the matches, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to delete the documents and re-add them so that the new `fieldType` changes take effect.

For details on how `stemming` works and the different type of stemming available you can have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis).

In your case the language is English so you could use the `PorterStemFilterFactory`.